# Is there any way to traverse all balanced bitvector?

Tags: algorithm, bitvector

Suppose a bit-vector with 2^n bits. It is a balanced bit-vector if it has exactly 2^(n-1) bit 1 (so does bit 0). Given n, can I print out all 2^n-bit balanced bit-vector in O(2^n)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Printing single 2^n bits vector takes O(2^n) time, and printing all possible vectors takes `O(2^n*nCr(2^n, 2^(n-1)))` - much more.